# Why does this suggested edit not show any tag changes I made?

Tags: discussion, support, tagging, editing, suggested-edits

A couple of days ago, I suggested an edit which was rejected, the reason being

> This edit introduces tags that do not help to define the topic of the question. Tags should help to describe what the question is *about*, not just what it *contains*.

Okay, I admit I don't remember which tags I added, so I referred [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1941068) however, it does not show the tag changes made, if any. So, I wanted to ask how can I view these changes, or are they visible to the reviewers only, or I did not make any tag changes and my edit was rejected for some other reason?

Comment: My guess is that a tag was added and was automatically pruned the next day. This could have happened if, say, some characters were accidentally entered in the "tags" field, leading to the creation of a new tag with no questions on it.

Comment: I have tried to check the same suggested edit using SEDE, to see whether something different is displayed there - but SEDE [shows no tags either](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1736564/data-about-the-suggested-edit-from-review-id?id=1941068).